# Setting background out of container

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am building a website with wordpress. The theme has a container set-up for all pages to set the width. I want to keep the text within the container width but set the background of the `<div>` on full width of a screen.

```
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: gray; background-size: 100%;">
<b>Malé tiské stěny</b><span style="font-weight: 400;">
</span><span style="font-weight: 400;">Na okruhu Malými stěnami čeká na návštěvníky devatenáct skalních útvarů. Za jejich poznáním vede značená cesta ze Skalního náměstí, která směřuje k Janusově hlavě, kde se trasa dělí. Okruh míří ke skalní soutěsce, kterou stoupá k Západní vyhlídce s výhledem na věže Velkých stěn, Tisou a Děčínský Sněžník. Následuje cesta soutěskou a pokračuje kolem Zpovědnice k Lesní bráně, Kazatelně a Kamennému stolu. Poté se objeví Herkules, Jeskyně Oblud, sluj Proviantura, Švédský tábor a masiv Hradu, který lze zdolat sestupem po schodech, nebo jej pohodlněji obejít po úpatí. Cesta vpravo do strže směruje ke schodišti, ze kterého se nabízí pohled na zaklíněný balvan Zvon. Další vyhlídka přibližuje Krušné hory a Rájecké skály. Stezka při úpatí Malých stěn se vine směrem k Bradavičnímu kameni, míjí Tunel a při pohledu zpátky nabídne pohled na Sloní nohu. Kolem Kuřích nožek vede k věži s Průlezem a odhalí dva Úly. V závěru se trasa vrací pohodlnou cestou na Skalní náměstí.</span>
</div>
```

This only gives the background to the container. Is there a way to set the full width background without touching the theme itself?

Comment: by using custom css you can set background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add some markup to the one you wrote above, you could extend the section and give a smaller box to the content. So, given this code:

```
<div class="wide-section">
   <div class="content-box">
     <b>Malé tiské stěny</b><span style="font-weight: 400;">
     </span><span style="font-weight: 400;">Test content.</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can extend your special section     beyond the main content width with this:

```
.wide-section{
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  background-color: grey;
}
```

And then give a smaller box to your content like this:

```
.content-box{
  margin: 0 auto; // center in some way if you need to
  width: [the width you need];
}
```

If you find a browser having horizontal scrollbar at some point, just play adding `overflow-x:hidden` to the body, html, both, or some inner element. You'll get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

as per your default class name you can add custom css.
For Example :

```
<style type="text/css">
   #hs-content .hs-container{ background-color: gray;}
</style>
```

Comment: this will change the background of the container, so it will have the width of the container. I want to give the full-width background...

Comment: please share your website link

Comment: http://tomas-nosek-testovaci.mzf.cz/skalni-mesto/ - the gray section should be gray on full width @Shital Marakana

Comment: The background is still not full width, but limited to container width... @Shital Marakana

Comment: use this code for whole page #hs-page{ background-color: gray !important;}

Comment: Add background for the content div like this #hs-content{background:gray;} and remove footer margin.

Answer (score 0):

`::before` and/or `::after`. Don't forget to use `content: " "`